# Deleting two points duplicate in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, duplicate

I have this kind of dataset below

| Point A | Point B |
| --- | --- |
| London | New York |
| Paris | Milan |
| New York | London |
| Madrid | Munich |
| Milan | Paris |
| ... | ... |

In this case, I consider London to New York and New York to London as a duplicate, and I want to delete the second. Milan to Paris is also a duplicate of Paris to Milan. The column is long, so I need to find an efficient way of doing it, rather than finding the duplicates manually.

Comment: Could you share what you have already tried?

Comment: This can be done with a helper column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert the following formula in `C2`:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A$2:A3,B3,B$2:B3,A3)+COUNTIFS(A$2:A3,A3,B$2:B3,B3)>1,"DUPLICATE","")
```

And populate down.

[image]

The formula looks for

Comment: It worked like magic! Thank you!
If you have time to elaborate the logic about the formula, I will really appreciate it. I don't understand the logical test in the IF formula.

Comment: OK, so it's not working like magic, but see the edit to my answer that provide a new and improved formula (the previous one failed to find some duplicates -- I noticed as I was trying to write an explanation for the previous formula)